# Get the frequency for each of the ngram terms using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am extracting the ngrams from a pandas dataframe using the following method:

```
def extractNGrams(df, ngram_size, min_freq):
    """Extract NGrams from a list of Strings
    Keyword arguments:
    df -- the pandas dataframe containing the sentences
    ngram_size -- defining the n for ngrams
    min_freq --- the minimum frequency for the ngram to be part of the set
    """
    vect = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(ngram_size,ngram_size), min_df=min_freq)
    lstSentences = df['Text'].values.tolist()
    X_train_counts = vect.fit_transform(lstSentences)    
    vocab = vect.get_feature_names()
    #print (vocab)
    print (X_train_counts.shape)
    return vocab
```

I wanted to understand the way to get the frequency for each of the ngram terms?

Comment: In the vocab variable you defined you have the mapping between the terms and feature indices. For instance {"word1":0, "word2":1}. The freq you need is given by the non-zero terms of your variable X_train_counts. That is, if the value of the first column is 2, that is "word1" occurs twice. Does this help?

Comment: @geompalik got it..!!  It helps..!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the code I used for getting counts

```
train_data_features = X_train_counts.toarray()
vocab = vect.get_feature_names()
dist = np.sum(train_data_features, axis=0)
ngram_freq = {}

# For each, print the vocabulary word and the frequency
for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
    #print(tag, count)
    ngram_freq[tag]=count
```

Comment: Do not use `.toarray()` since this will convert the sparse matrix to a dense matrix. Just leave it out

Comment: That is, should the first line be `train_data_features = X_train_counts` ?